# Measuring the density of surface antigens

Tags: cell-biology

I'm trying to get a sense of the variety of methods used for determining the number of cell surface antigens and receptors. This is notably different from determining the affinity of these surface markers.

Comment: Are you looking for extraction techniques, or techniques to analyze your extracted molecules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to count numbers of both antigens and receptors in live cell?

Possible ways:

1. FRET (unlikely to work)
2. imaging of receptors with single molecule resolution
3. western blot to roughly estimate amount of receptors
4. single cell proteomics techniques (not very suitable)

Comment: FRET could work. He'd have to tag both the antigen and antibody, though He probably would be better off with standard fluorescence spectroscopy.